# sqlite: how to add total time hh:mm:ss where column datatype is DATETIME?

Tags: database, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image: COLUMN]

This is the snapshot of my column in sqlite db and its datatype in schema is defined has **DATETIME**. Now I want to apply some aggregation function like `sum()` to calculate the total of this column.

the query that I used is:

`select sum(total_expend_time) from timetable;` but it returns 0.0 as result.

Comment: If you are in search of a quick answer then this is what , finally helped me `SELECT time(sum(strftime('%s', total_expend_time) -
           strftime('%s', '00:00:00')), 'unixepoch') FROM timetable`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SQLite has no native `DATETIME` data type; the values are stored as strings.

You have to use a [built-in date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to convert from these strings to a number of seconds before you can add them:

```
SELECT sum(strftime('%s', total_expend_time) -
           strftime('%s', '00:00:00'       ))
FROM timetable
```

If you want to have this formatted as a time, you have to convert it back afterwards:

```
SELECT time(sum(...), 'unixepoch') FROM timetable
```

Comment: what will this return `SELECT sum(strftime('%s', total_expend_time) -
           strftime('%s', '00:00:00'       ))
FROM timetable` number of seconds , as in my case it is returning 1770 what is that value.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote, and what the documentation for `%s` says.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me:

```
SELECT time(
           sum( strftime('%s', total_expend_time) ),
           'unixepoch'
           )
FROM timetable
```

thank you CL!